# matrix product rank using orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Came across this fact in a book. Wasn't sure why it was true. Given a Matrix M= ABA' where A an orthogonal matrix, why is the rank(B)=rank(M).

Comment: $A$ is orthogonal and $|A|=+/-1 \ne 0$ and thus $A$ is invertible. I suppose you know the fact that multiplication, left or right, by a full-rank matrix does not change rank.

Comment: @Vim I think you are wrong in saying multiplication by full rank matrix,rather what I know is that "multiplication, left or right, by a full-rank $\mathbf{square}$matrix does not change rank".I don't know whether it is true in general as said by you.

Comment: @lbs it's true in general, not just for square matrices.